# 2 Rows Owl Carousel or BX Slider

Tags: bxslider, owl-carousel

Is it possible to make 2 rows slider on desktop and become 1 row on mobile screen with Owl Carousel or BX Slider? I've try some but still in 2 rows on mobile. Would you please help?

[image: 2 Rows Slider on Desktop > 1 Row on Mobile]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for Owl carousel 2, which allows to control box quantity:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      autoplay:true,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 1
        },
        600: {
           items: 2
        },
        1000: {
          items: 3
        }
      }
    });
});
```

The idea is to declare how much boxes you need in different widths.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.carousel').slick({
        rows: 2,
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 640,
      settings: {
        rows: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    }]
});
```